# hitbox of text too big

Tags: html, css

I have 2 texts on my page and both of them turn white on hover with an animation. But the hitbox of the text is too big in width, which means that it lights up way too soon (when you're not even close to the text). Does anyone know why this is happening?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#page-header {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  height: 65%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

#start-introduction:hover {
  animation-name: changeColor;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#start-introduction {
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 15vh;
  font-size: 7vh;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #262626;
  cursor: default;
  animation-name: reverseColor;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

#introduction:hover {
  animation-name: changeColor;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#introduction {
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 3vh;
  font-size: 18vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: #262626;
  font-family: arial;
  cursor: default;
  animation-name: reverseColor;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes changeColor {
  from {
    color: #262626;
  }
  to {
    color: white;
  }
}

@keyframes reverseColor {
  from {
    color: white;
  }
  to {
    color: #262626;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="page-header">
  <p id="start-introduction">test test</p>
  <h1 id="introduction">{Test test}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: All of the tags you used are block level and will take up the full width of their container by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a few things to go over. I'm going to make a few assumptions here and see if this helps. Paragraphs `<p>` and Headers `h1` are block level elements this means they will always span the width of their containing element which in your case is `<div id="page-header">`. So when you say that you want an animation to take place when you `:hover` an element that includes the entire element. The point I am trying to make is: if you only want the animation to take place when you hover the text. You need to make the element only as wide as the text. In this case I place them both in their own containers and make those containers display flex so the elements inside are no longer block level elements and can easily be placed in the center using justify content.

On a side note I would be careful using Viewport height `vh` as a unit of measurement for margins and font size.  I understand you want your font sizes to be responsive but using viewport height is too risky and your numbers could end up  being all over the place unless you are 100% sure that everyone will have the same size screen and it will always be full size.  I personally use `em` and/or `rem` for my font sizes and margins because `em` is based on the parent element font size or `rem` which is based on the document font size.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#page-header {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  height: 65%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

#start-introduction:hover {
  animation-name: changeColor;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#start-introduction {
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 15vh;
  font-size: 7vh;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #262626;
  cursor: default;
  animation-name: reverseColor;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

#introduction:hover {
  animation-name: changeColor;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#introduction {
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 3vh;
  font-size: 18vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: #262626;
  font-family: arial;
  cursor: default;
  animation-name: reverseColor;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes changeColor {
  from {
    color: #262626;
  }
  to {
    color: white;
  }
}

@keyframes reverseColor {
  from {
    color: white;
  }
  to {
    color: #262626;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  <title>TestTest</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page-header">
    <div class="container">
      <p id="start-introduction">test test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 id="introduction">{Test test}</h1>
    </div>
    
    
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving it a width? Also, the font size of the above 'test text' and '{Test test}' texts are not equal.

Comment: I have tried to to adjust the width but that isn't fixing the problem unfortunately. Also, the text element sizes are right but the hitbox is just way too wide

Comment: Can you send me the image you want to see? I can help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).